# SurveyMonkey API: No folder support?

Tags: api, surveymonkey

It looks like neither get_survey_list or get_survey_details returns any info about the folder(s) that any given survey is in.  Is this something that will be supported in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that should be asked to the original developers.

Comment: I buy that.  On developer.surveymonkey.com they seem to indicate that SO is the preferred method of asking them questions, though, so I thought I'd start here.

Comment: Mmm, ok, I've removed my close vote. For information, I got here because SO detected "low quality" on your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; appreciated! If nothing comes of this question, I'll send their dev team an email and post the answer back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not in our plans, but I've noted your request for it, thanks for the input!

Comment: Thanks Miles!  As surveys can be 'grouped' by placing them in folders, it seems like being able to include a folder parameter in the API call would be a good way to get said groupings of surveys back.  Thanks again for the response.

Comment: Agreed - we're in the process of adding better support for this to the rest of our site, so I've put in a feature request to tie it into that.